# How can I associate hbs file with handlebar mode?

Tags: spacemacs

`hbs` are file extension for [`handlebar` template](http://handlebarsjs.com/) files

When I tried to open the file, spacemacs automatically associate it with 'Web' mode.

[image]

Is there a mode for handlebar? If so, how can I change the mode by default for `hbs` files?

Comment: `web-mode` [claims to be compatible with `handlebars`](http://web-mode.org/). Have you tried searching online or in `M-x list-packages RET` for a `handlebars` mode? I see the options [`handlebars-sgml-mode`](https://github.com/jacott/handlebars-sgml-mode) and [`handlebars-mode`](https://github.com/danielevans/handlebars-mode).

Comment: As for associating extensions with major modes, see the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoModeAlist), [ergoemacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_auto-activate_a_major-mode.html), this [answer to an Emacs SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/637/15748) and the authoritative Emacs Manual node on [Auto Major Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html).