# How to associate a theme to a file extension?

Tags: init-file, themes

It is kind of similar to this question [How do I automatically load a mode for a specific set of file extensions?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/636/how-do-i-automatically-load-a-mode-for-a-specific-set-of-file-extensions)

So I am in a situation where, when I want to write in TeX, I want to use 'whiteboard' theme.
Whereas whenever I want to program in C++ or python, I want to use "afternoon" theme.

I kind of expect my init file to look like

```
(if [file extention is tex] (load-theme 'whiteboard t) (load-theme 'afternoon t))
```

Is this right?

I am using Emacs 26.3

Comment: You may be interested in investigating how to make a theme buffer-local and apply that theme to the file-visiting-buffer, rather than applying a new theme globally ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different themes in different modes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43674/different-themes-in-different-modes)

Answer (score 1):

A theme is global, but you can cause a given theme to be used when you visit a file with a given major mode: You can use the mode hook of a mode you're interested in to start using the theme you want for that mode.

`auto-mode-alist` associates file types (extensions) with major modes, and each major mode has a mode hook. So you can associate file types with themes by using mode hooks to turn on given themes.

IOW:

- file extension => specific major mode
- major mode's hook => specific theme

The theme you change to because of a mode hook will then be used everywhere (all buffers, all modes), until you visit a file with a different mode, whose mode hook says to use a different theme. That behavior might not be what you want. But it's one possibility to consider.